# Highcharts graph not filling Bootstrap box

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm trying to display a highcharts graph inside of the Bootstrap AdmimLTE template. 
I am using the content class section to hold a box class with a highcharts graph inside of it.

```
<section class="content">
  <!-- Default box -->
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
           <div id='chartID'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
</section>
```

When using the chart without the adminLTE template, I can set the height to 100% like as seen in this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkkAd/149/

When I place the chart in the adminLTE template, the height attributes are not resizing the graph to fit 100% of the box.
The only way I can change the height is by manually setting the height of the graph by pixels and not by percentage.
The highcharts documentation states that the height of the graph is dynamically as long as you set a height on the chart's containing element. It can be a fixed number or a even a percent if position is absolute.

The box class already has a default height of 100%, and setting the box-body to 100% doesn't work either.

Any ideas on how to make the content within the box or box-body class all 100%?

Answer (score 0):

In div with class `box-body` add div with class `row` and div with class `col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12` after that the highchart div .So final layout will be

```
<section class="content">
   <!-- SELECT2 EXAMPLE -->
   <div class="box">
      <div class="box-header with-border">
         <h3 class="box-title">Select2</h3>
         <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-header -->
      <div class="box-body">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
               <div id="container" style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- /.row -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.box-body -->
      <div class="box-footer">
         Visit <a href="https://select2.github.io/">Select2 documentation</a> for more examples and information about the plugin.
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

My sample with above layout without any extra modification in theme(chrome browser)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have tried what you have described and it is not working for me. To replicate, I downloaded a fresh copy of AdminLTE and Highcharts. I did not modify the style for anything and just dropped your code in with a highcharts demo graph. Same results...  Do you have a box below this main box ? wondering if that box is filling the screen height in your example. Are you able to place the graph like displayed in your image with out a second row?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know this may not be the best way to accomplish the task, but after reading many review of the same problem, I came to a solution that worked for me.
This may not work for you, but if using bootstrap, it may be an option to try.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#chartID').height( $(window).height() 
                    - $(".navbar").height() 
                    - $(".main-footer").height() 
                    - $(".main-header").height()
                    - $(".box-header").height()
                    - $(".box-footer").height()
                    - parseInt($('#cws_blocks').css("margin-bottom"))
                    - parseInt($('#cws_blocks').css("margin-top"))
                    - parseInt($(".main-sidebar").css("padding-bottom"))
                    - parseInt($('.content').css("padding-bottom"))
                    - parseInt($('.content').css("padding-top"))
                    - parseInt($(".main-footer").css("padding-bottom"))
                    - parseInt($(".main-footer").css("padding-top")) 
                    - parseInt($(".box").css("padding-bottom"))
                    - parseInt($(".box").css("padding-top")) 
                    - parseInt($(".box-header").css("padding-bottom"))
                    - parseInt($(".box-header").css("padding-top")) 
                    - parseInt($(".box-footer").css("padding-bottom"))
                    - parseInt($(".box-footer").css("padding-top"))                     
                    );  
    })
    $(window).resize();
```

Also, this may be a bit overkill, but currently it is the solution that works for . I basically just resize the height of the highcharts div by subtracting the height and padding of elements above and below graph. 
This works when only the graph is on the page. 
Also, is responsive. Testing on pc, not mobile.

If anyone know a better way to do this, please update.

Found this trick here and modified to work for me: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1671